# Start multiple threads at same time and UnitTest it

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was wondering how do I test that the code I was running actually begun in the same time...

***Here's a piece of code:***

```
var threads = new List<Thread>
{
  new Thread(() => Call1stFunc()),
  new Thread(() => Call2ndFunc())
}
threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());              
threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
```

How do I unit test it and verify that the thread's executed in the same time?
If my code is wrong how I would know what is the correct code to execute such task?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to test here?

Comment: sounds like you're trying to test behavior of `Start()` method (that it starts tasks on the same time) and this is definitely not a unit test but rather integration test towards behavior of external dll...

Comment: @tchrikch I suppose, one question for you, I want to do it without using TPL, can you show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't start threads at exactly same time and the order of execution is not determined. But you can use synchronization constructs to synchronize you threads. For instance, use ManualResetEventSlim to force your threads to wait until it set.

For unit testing you can use thread number and time marker. Just store them in List and then compare start times with delta.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ids = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };

    var manualResetEventSlim = new ManualResetEventSlim();

    foreach (var id in ids)
    {
        var thread = new Thread((obj) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("thread {0} strated", obj as string));
            manualResetEventSlim.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("thread {0} work in progress", obj as string);
        });

        thread.Start(id);
   }

   Console.ReadKey();

   manualResetEventSlim.Set();

   Console.ReadKey();

}
```