# How to start mutiple threads at the same time in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, timer

My project has 2 threads that use System.Timer

```
Thread t1, t2;
t1 = new Thread(Timer_product);
t2 = new Thread(Timer_money);
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

When I run the application, it always starts t1, but doesn't start t2.

If I change the order to

```
t2.Start();
t1.Start();
```

and run my app again, t1 doesn't start, but t2 starts.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what Timer_product and Timer_money are exactly?

Comment: Please include the code that defines `Timer_product` and `Timer_money`.  A complete, working snippet of code is best.

Comment: "2 threads that use System.Timer"? Why would you need new thread to start timer at all? Definitly need [MCVE] to diagnose problem (i.e. using shared timer variable).

Comment: Include your timer code and change the question title.  Your issue is not in Threads.

Comment: perhaps you could have done a google search for examples on how to create and or run multiple threads in C# why is it that people do not know how to use google these days

Answer (score 0):

The order of thread execution doesn't matter as demonstrated below. I suspect your issue lies in *Timer_money* or possibly *Timer_product*.

**Examples:**

```
void Main()
{
    Thread t1, t2;
    t1 = new Thread(t => { Console.WriteLine("T1 is running");});
    t2 = new Thread(t => { Console.WriteLine("T2 is running");});
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start(); 
}
```

**Results:**

> T1 is running
>   T2 is running

Now the same Threads but with reversed order of execution.

```
void Main()
{
    Thread t1, t2;
    t1 = new Thread(t => { Console.WriteLine("T1 is running");});
    t2 = new Thread(t => { Console.WriteLine("T2 is running");});
    t2.Start(); 
    t1.Start();
}
```

**Results:**

> T2 is running
>   T1 is running

Answer (score 0):

When using timer you don't need threads at all, because timer already use it's own thread. [Take a look at code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,897683f27faba082).

So, you probably need thread synchronization if you use two different timers. See my [answer how to synchronize threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089726/start-multiple-threads-at-same-time-and-unittest-it/42534251#42534251)

Answer (score -2):

How about using Parallel.Invoke()?

```
Parallel.Invoke(Timer_product, Timer_money);
```

If this doesn't work neither, the problem should be inside Timer_product or Timer_money. It would help you to find out what the problem is anyway.

Comment: Please provide and explanation why do you believe this will help OP? Currently there is no reason to believe that the problem is in any way related to starting thread (as demonstrated in other post http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049719/477420)

Comment: Thanks, I've added some explanations to my answer. I thought this might be helpful to figure out what the exact problem is.

Answer (score -3):

The Parallel.Invoke method provides a convenient way to run any number of arbitrary statements concurrently. Just pass in an Action delegate for each item of work. The easiest way to create these delegates is to use lambda expressions.

The following example shows a basic Invoke call that creates and starts two tasks that run concurrently. The first task is represented by a lambda expression that calls a method named `DoSomeWork`, and the second task is represented by a lambda expression that calls a method named `DoSomeOtherWork.`

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomeWork(), () => DoSomeOtherWork());
```

Comment: Please check comment on the other Invoke suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049614/how-to-start-mutiple-threads-at-the-same-time-in-c#comment-53920323 and consider adding explanation to your post.